# Delayed stringification without macro expansion

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

Is it possible to modify the following code fragment to prevent the  diagnostic printed by `#pragma GCC warning` from changing if any of the identifier tokens in `deprecation_message` are defined as object-like macros at the point where `dmacro` is expanded, while preserving the ability to substitute `symbol` into the message?  Ugliness no object, GCC extensions are fair game as long as clang also implements them, but the contents of the diagnostic may not be modified.

```
#define deprecation_message(symbol) \
   #symbol will be removed from <header.h> in the next release\n\
   of $LIBRARY. To use #symbol, include <moved/header.h> instead.

#define make_pw(...) make_pw_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define make_pw_(...) make_pw__(GCC warning #__VA_ARGS__)
#define make_pw__(...) _Pragma(#__VA_ARGS_)

#define dmacro(a,b,c) make_pw(deprecation_message(dmacro)) xmacro(a,b,c)

// Uncommenting any of the following #define lines should *not*
// change the text of the diagnostic in any way.
//#define header
//#define n f
//#define will won't'
dmacro(x,y,z)
```

(You might be tempted to reach for string-literal concatenation, but that won't work; both `_Pragma` itself and `#pragma GCC warning` accept only a single string literal.  `_Pragma("this" "that")` is a syntax error.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood the question, but the following code is working and compiling on both `clang` and `gcc`, and tested with `-std=c99` and `-std=c11`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define deprecation_message(symbol) \
   #symbol " will be removed from <header.h> in the next release\n" \
   "of $LIBRARY. To use " #symbol ", include <moved/header.h> instead."

#define make_pw__(...) _Pragma(#__VA_ARGS__)
#define make_pw_(...)  make_pw__(GCC warning #__VA_ARGS__)
#define make_pw(...)   make_pw_(__VA_ARGS__)

#define xmacro(a, b, c) puts("I'm working: " #a #b #c "!")
#define dmacro(a, b, c) make_pw(deprecation_message(dmacro)) xmacro(a, b, c)

int
main(void)
{
    dmacro(x, y, z);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now, the above code will expand this with `clang`:

```
int
main(void)
{
    #pragma GCC warning "\042dmacro\042 \042 will be removed from <header.h> in the next release\134n\042 \042of $LIBRARY. To use \042 \042dmacro\042 \042, include <moved/header.h> instead.\042"
    puts("I'm working: " "x" "y" "z" "!");
    return 0 /* Successful exit status.  */;
}
```

and will produce the following warnings on `clang`:

```
src/main.c:18:5: warning: "dmacro" " will be removed from <header.h> in the next release\n" "of $LIBRARY. To use " "dmacro" ", include <moved/header.h> instead." [-W#pragma-messages]
    dmacro(x, y, z);
    ^
```

and this on `gcc`:

```
src/main.c:18:13: warning: "dmacro" " will be removed from <header.h> in the next release\n" "of $LIBRARY. To use " "dmacro" ", include <moved/header.h> instead."
     dmacro(x, y, z);
             ^~~~~~~~
```

Basically all I did was, to put the deprecation message into quotes...

---

**UPDATE<sup>1</sup>:**

Now, the funny thing is, if you remove the stringification from `make_pw_`, that is:

```c
#define make_pw_(...)  make_pw__(GCC warning __VA_ARGS__)
```

then `clang` will give you this:

```
src/main.c:18:5: warning: dmacro will be removed from <header.h> in the next releaseof $LIBRARY. To use dmacro, include <moved/header.h> instead. [-W#pragma-messages]
    dmacro(x, y, z);
    ^
```

Which is nice, as it does not have the unwanted quotes, however `GCC` will only give you this:

```
src/main.c:18:13: warning: dmacro
     dmacro(x, y, z);
             ^~~~~~~~
```

What is even more strange, is that if you change the `deprecation_message` to this:

```c
#define deprecation_message(symbol) "" #symbol "..."
```

then it will give you an empty warning, like it was only using the first non-white-space token from the macro argument.

To be honest with you, I don't know if this is a bug from `GCC`, or this is the well-defined behavior and `clang` is doing some extra work to make sense out of this, none the less, this is happening with the latest versions of the two compilers. *(If I have to bet, I would say, this is a bug :P)*

---

**UPDATE<sup>2</sup>:**

Here is a slightly modified version, which works on both compilers as you described in your comment. The trick is, that the macro `DEPRECATED` has two stages, instead of one.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEPRECATED_(...) #__VA_ARGS__
#define DEPRECATED(symbol)                                                     \
    DEPRECATED_(#symbol will be removed from <header.h> in the next release\n  \
                of $LIBRARY. To use #symbol, include <moved/header.h> instead.)

#define PRAGMA_WARN_(message) _Pragma(#message)
#define PRAGMA_WARN(message)  PRAGMA_WARN_(GCC warning message)

#define dmacro(a, b, c)                                                        \
    PRAGMA_WARN(DEPRECATED(dmacro))                                            \
    puts("I'm working: " #a #b #c "!")

int
main(void)
{
    dmacro(x, y, z);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So this will produce the following output in `clang`:

```
src/main.c:19:5: warning: "dmacro" will be removed from <header.h> in the next release of $LIBRARY. To use "dmacro", include <moved/header.h> instead. [-W#pragma-messages]
    dmacro(x, y, z);
    ^
```

And the following one in `GCC`:

```
src/main.c:19:13: warning: "dmacro" will be removed from <header.h> in the next release
 of $LIBRARY. To use "dmacro", include <moved/header.h> instead.
     dmacro(x, y, z);
             ^~~~~~~~
```

***NOTE:*** I would highly recommend you, to remove the `\n` character from your message!

Comment: I shall have to do some experimentation around this apparent-bug myself, but for right now, just to be clear, when I said "the contents of the diagnostic may not be modified", I meant to rule out anything that would add extra quotation marks to the compiler's output.

Comment: @zwol I updated my answer, now all the unnecessary quotes are gone and it is working on both wished compilers!

Comment: @zwol if you think this answer was helpful, please consider accepting it, before the end of the bounty-period! cheers!